# Ping one remote server from another remote server

Tags: c#

It's simple to ping a server in C#, but suppose I have servers A, B and C.

A connects to B.

A asks B to ping C, to check that B can talk to C.

A needs to read the outcome.

Now, first of all is this possible without installing an application onto B? In other words, can I perform the entire check from just running a program on A?

If so, can anyone suggest the route I would take to achieve this? I've looked at sockets but from the examples I've seen these require a client AND server application to function.

Comment: Probably this nice web service is what you need? http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/

Comment: Thanks but this will actually be used to check communication between remote servers, not whether a specific server is down.

Comment: Unless you can simply tunnel a connection through B (not sure how practical that is in Windows), I can't see how you'd do this without having at least some sort of software running on B to act as the middle man.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this sounds like something that you shouldn't be trying to do.

For example, if you have some application on A that calls B which in turn calls C, then it shouldn't be the responsibility of A to figure out why isn't B working. Simply call B and if it doesn't work, then it doesn't work.

Now, if you really want to do this, you would need some service on B that forwards the request to C (or something like that). If you don't want to install anything on B, then the only way is to (ab)use some service that's already installed on it. But I can't think of any common service that would allow you to do this.

Comment: Just to clarify, A would actually be a monitoring service which checks a whole host of servers are able to communicate with each other. So A is only interested in whether B can talk to C, and alert if it can't. But as you say I now think this isn't easily possible without some abusive method, so thank you for your advice.